# Passing parameters from one configuration to another in TeamCity

Tags: automation, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

Trying to send parameters from one TeamCity configuration to another.

I have 2 build configurations. One deploying updates to multiple data-centers and the other running E2E tests on selected data-centers (currently running manually after successful deployments)

My goal is to automate the process. The deploy configuration also runs a script checking which data-centers successfully received the updates. I want the E2E configuration to automatically run only on data-centers which successfully received the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it has been a long time, but this question may be of interest to anyone else.

I encountered a similar problem recently – needed to get the build parameter from configuration A in build from configuration B. The only method I can think of is using the TeamCity REST API.

You should just modify configuration B and add the build step, which will sequentially get build_id from configuration A, then get the build parameter at its id and pass a parameter to build B.

Get builds list of configuration A (for example, you can get the last build):

```
<teamcity_server>/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:<configuration_A_id>,branch:default:any
```

Get build parameters of build A:

```
<teamcity_server>/app/rest/builds/id:<build_id>/resulting-properties
```

Read TeamCity REST API documentation for more: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html